# Need a SQL query to generate output only for latest data

Tags: sql

I have a table called Customer like below

[image: customer table]

I need query which genearate output like below
[image: Output]

Below are the details

1. I need the city_name and customer_name as output
2. Have to select only one new customer from each city based on the date(descending order)

I need a query to satisfy above scenrio using subquery/joins/etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have multiple databases tagged? Keep the one you're actually using.

Comment: SQL is a language, not a database. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle etc are what we call databases

Comment: Have you tried anything???

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server, you can use window functions. (many other SQL engines also has window functions, check their specifications)

```
; WITH cte AS (
    SELECT city_name, customer_name
   , RN = ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY city_name, customer_name ORDER BY Date DESC )
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with a `correlated subquery`

```
select a.city_name, a.customer_name
from customers a
where date = (select max(b.date)
              from customers b
              where a.city_name=b.city_name);
```

Can be written as an `uncorrelated subquery` too

```
select city_name, customer_name
from customers
where (city_name, date) in (select city_name, max(date)
                            from customers
                            group by city_name);
```